# Serving back-end data from memory (rather than a DB)

Tags: javascript, json, database, express

I'm thinking of writing a small SPA that serves as a sort of "database" viewer for assets in a video game (vehicles, weapons, etc. that players can use).  I want users to be able to form advanced queries about what types of vehicles/weapons/etc. they want to see based on a range of properties each of those objects has (in the way that you can filter down items in Amazon or Newegg based on the values of item properties).

My question has to do with where and how to store that data.

It takes the form of a 10MB JSON file, far too large just to bundle into the client-side code of the SPA, meaning I'm going to have to serve it from a back-end somehow (probably an Express app).  I could easily throw this into MongoDB, but I'm wondering if perhaps that's overkill.

In a case like this, where your data is on the order of 10MB (an array of ~10,000 items), could your Express app simply load the JSON file into an array of item objects in memory, and have the REST endpoints just perform native JavaScript array operations to filter and sort the main collection to generate the subarray (or single item) to return?  Is there any reason *not* to do this?

Obviously if your data is of a certain size, you would want to throw it in a database, but I'm very fuzzy on where that cutoff point is or how you would make that determination (assuming that what I proposed isn't totally ludicrous).

Comment: Have you considered using `service worker` ?

Comment: I don't know much about them.  How could they help in this situation?

Comment: You could cache ur static resources with them

Comment: You might also want to consider [SQLite for node](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3). It's a full fledged SQL DB that's contained in a file. No server needed. That being said, I'd definitely go with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not changing the contents of your object much, it's certainly possible and easy to do. There are even fairly robust querying options for you.  If you need to update the info, then you'll limit scalability by keeping it all in memory and increase the risk of losing data.

Update

For querying, I'm assuming you're running the recent versions of Node that support ES5 and 6 array prototypes.  If so, using Array.filter is a great basic query.  If you need more complicated or complex  stuff or can't rely on modern JavaScript the next option would be Lodash, which has pretty rich collection operations.

Comment: This would be read only, so there wouldn't be any data to lose (that I don't already have anyway).  What querying options would you recommend?